# toggleclass onclick

Tags: jquery

For my site i have a div with content.

Above the div i have tabs like:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <div id="tab1" class="tab" onclick="tabClick('tab1');">
      Info
   </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="tab" onclick="tabClick('tab2');">
      Video
   </div>
   <div id="tab3" class="tab" onclick="tabClick('tab3');">
      Serie
   </div>
</div>
```

if i click i want to toggle the class: tabactive.

I have the jquery:

```
function tabClick(id)
{
     $(id).toggleClass("tabactief");      //add the class to the clicked element
}
```

but it aint working, is it wrong to use onclick to request a jquery action?

what i want to do is toggle the class of the clicked div to tabactief.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to this:

```
$('#' + id).toggleClass("tabactief");
```

Comment: if the answer is correct please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `#` before `id` for [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

```
 $('#' + id).toggleClass("tabactief");
```

Alternatively you can pass `#` with `id` from where you call `tabClick`

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab" onclick="tabClick('#tab1');">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#'+id).toggleClass("Active");
```

This is what you are looking for i think.